# SUPPORTED_TYPE error when setting up a net-ssh connection

Tags: ruby, cygwin, net-ssh

Has anyone out there seen this error before?  I haven't been able to find any reference to SUPPORTED_TYPE in the source...

> irb(main):013:0> connection = Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => 'password')
>
>
> NameError: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::KnownHosts::SUPPORTED_TYPE       
> from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:117:in `keys_for'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:105:in `each_line'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:105:in `keys_for'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:103:in `open'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:103:in `keys_for'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:33:in `search_in'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:33:in `map'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:33:in `search_in'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:27:in `search_for'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:237:in `prepare_preferred_algorithms!'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:120:in `initialize'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:79:in `new'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:79:in `initialize'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:186:in `new'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.5.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:186:in `start'
>         from (irb):13
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1313

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easier solution is to use [this forked version](http://github.com/nessche/net-ssh) of net-ssh which fixes that issue (the next release of the official net-ssh gem should fix it as well) as described [here](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/pull/46).

If you have that issue while deploying through capistrano (which I had today), you can install [this net-ssh version](http://github.com/nessche/net-ssh) from github through the Gemfile and then call cap by using `bundle exec cap deploy`.

Put in the Gemfile `gem 'net-ssh', :git => 'git://github.com/nessche/net-ssh.git'`.

Comment: Thanks!  That workaround helped me out for a while and it looked like they got a new official gem out pretty quickly in the github link you provided.  The version where the fix is is 2.5.2.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem that seems to have been introduced by the May 24th updates 2.5.0 or 2.5.1 to the net-ssh gem. You can find the constant SUPPORTED_TYPE here:

http://net-ssh.github.com/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH/KnownHosts.html

I don't know all the details, but there have been a couple solutions to this issue so far. One is to remove your known_hosts file (or the particular host you're trying to connect to from that file), and you might be able to connect until that host is added to known_hosts again -- it will return the same error if it's in there, for some reason.

The second option I've found is to revert to version 2.4.0 of the gem. I've submitted a ticket for the issue at:

http://net-ssh.lighthouseapp.com/projects/36253-net-ssh/tickets/58-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-netsshknownhostssupported_type

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Clarif's solution to this looks like a more acceptable one. Thanks, Clarif!

Answer (score 1):

After following the issues on github and also applying what clarif suggested, I came up with this that fixed my problem.

http://tinyurl.com/cxr2xa3